# Getting JSON for a model and its associations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, associations, has-many

I have 3 models.

```
 Venue :has_many :events
 Events :has_many :event_dates
```

Im spitting out

```
 events: <%= venue.events.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Which works correctly. But I also need an array of the event dates within each event. Im sure there is a very long winded way of doing this comparing ids, but im looking for an elegant solution.

Make Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `to_json` on a model you can pass `:include` options to include associations (see the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)):

```
venue.events.to_json(:include => :event_dates)
```